# Problem with using if statement in react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

Validation in react-hook-form using if, else statement return only when return value is true. But if the statement is false it returns nothing.

[image][image]

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    getValues,
    formState: { isValid }
  } = useForm({
    mode: "onChange",
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: ""
    }
  });

  const onSubmit = () => {
    if (isValid) {
      console.log("valid");
    } else {
      console.log("invalid");
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input type="text" {...register("firstName", { required: true })} />
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" {...register("lastName", { required: true })} />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I don't know what's wrong. Can someone help please.

[Here's the code from codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v6-formstate-forked-v5f2qg?file=/src/index.jsx:0-895)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think anything is wrong with the code. If you only enter the last name and hit submit, it highlights the first name box. And same for the opposite. If you only enter the first name and hit submit, it highlights the second box. This seems to me like a default behavior from the react hook form. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xzz2xu?file=src/App.js) you can see I added a useEffect to it to print out the validity. When the form is valid you can see it shows correctly.

This seems to be a feature from the react hook form to prevent submitting if it is not valid.

Edit: Look into their `import { ErrorMessage } from "@hookform/error-message";` system they have in place. And [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v6-formstate-forked-7tpv53?file=/src/index.jsx:114-169) is an updated code sandbox with error handling

Comment: I see. I was trying to show some kind of error message if it wasn't valid or a valid message if it was valid then once the form is successfully summited it will show a success message. That was what I was trying to do. Any advice?

Comment: Check my edit. The hook form has a package for error handling. You can add that to the form.

Answer (score 0):

Your form wont submit unless required fields are entered on inputs:

```
     const onSubmit = () => {
    if (!isValid) {
      console.log("valid");
    } else {
      console.log("invalid");
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input type="text" {...register("firstName")} />
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" {...register("lastName")} />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};
```